# How to correctly (and effectively) release memory in a gtk widget

Tags: c, memory-management, gtk, valgrind

I'm trying to understand how to correctly release memory when I am finished with a GTK widget, for example if I need to create and destroy many widgets. However, valgrind seems to indicate a memory leak regardless of what I try. I've looked at other questions, including one that lists a valgrind supression file for GTK, but it didn't change the result.

Here's the simplest code snippet to reproduce my issue:

```
#include "gtk/gtk.h"

int main()
{
    GtkWidget * widget = gtk_fixed_new();
    g_object_ref(widget);
    g_object_ref_sink(widget); // remove floating reference, and own this object ourselves

    g_object_unref(widget);

    gtk_widget_destroy(widget);
}
```

My expectation is that (after dealing with floating references), the unref() function should reduce the reference count to zero, and then all memory is released. I threw the gtk_widget_destroy() in there for good measure, but I'm not sure it should actually be necessary (and it doesn't change the magnitude of the leak).

The output with the valgrind command `G_SLICE=debug-blocks valgrind ./t3 --supression=~/Downloads/GNOME.supp` from question [Memory Leaks in GTK hello_world program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program)
is

```
==10079== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10079==     in use at exit: 164,338 bytes in 847 blocks
==10079==   total heap usage: 1,380 allocs, 533 frees, 219,176 bytes allocated
==10079== 
==10079== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10079==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10079==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10079==      possibly lost: 21,350 bytes in 174 blocks
==10079==    still reachable: 142,988 bytes in 673 blocks
==10079==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10079== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

The other documentation I've looked at is http://www.demko.ca/blog/posts/200705_gtkmm_refcoutning.txt and https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkObject.html

You can compile my snippet with

```
gcc -std=gnu99 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` t3.c -o t3 `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gthread-2.0`
```

Anyone know what I'm missing? Is there another function I should be calling to ensure the memory is released?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 - g_object_ref

  Increases ref count by one

 - g_object_unref

  Decreases ref count by one, if ref count == 0, the object is destroyed

 - g_object_ref_sink

  IF the object has a floating ref, it converts that reference to a normal ref (sinks it)
  ELSE it increases the ref count by one

 - All objects start with a floating ref count of 1
```

For some further reading, I would suggest you take a look at the following article: [Introduction to Memory Management in GTK+](http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/course_materials/csci493.70/lecture_notes/GTK_memory_mngmt.pdf)

Now, moving on to your example, lets look at the function calls and what they do:

```
GtkWidget * widget = gtk_fixed_new(); //widget created with ref count of 1 | floating = true
g_object_ref(widget); // floating = true, ref count increased to 2
g_object_ref_sink(widget); // floating = false, ref count remains at 2

g_object_unref(widget); // floating = false, ref count decreases to 1

//No further unrefs, hello leak!
```

I hope that explains your leak, be sure to read the article mentioned above.

Comment: But doesn't `gtk_widget_destroy()` unref it yet again? Does the leak disappear if you remove the `g_object_ref()` call? I rather think the answer might be due to GLib not cooperating very well with Valgrind.

Comment: `gdk_destroy()` just sends the signal to politely ask everyone to remove their references, but doesn't force any references to disappear. The issue was that I somehow misunderstood the effect of `ref_sink()`, which does NOT need to paired with a `ref()` call.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the opposite behavior of [g_closure_sink](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Closures.html#g-closure-sink).

Answer (score 1):

`g_object_is_floating` is an api call which can be used to find if gtk object is floating point reference counted or not. Here is a link to example code:
http://wikistack.com/managing-gtk-memorygui-application-interview-question/