# Memory leak in gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib, gdk, gdkpixbuf

Valgrind reports a [memory leak](http://pastebin.com/7JAzAxzP) when I run this simple test program:

```
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
int main() {
    GdkPixbuf* buf;
    GError* err = NULL;
    buf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("test.jpg", &err);
    g_assert_no_error(err);
    g_object_unref(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware of the issues regarding Valgrind and GLib/GDK/GTK, and of the several StackOverflow answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program), [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732598/how-to-correctly-and-effectively-release-memory-in-a-gtk-widget), and others) regarding this issue.

For GLib it's enough to prefix the `valgrind` command with `G_DEBUG=gc-friendly G_SLICE=always-malloc` (though I still have some "still reacheable" leaks, which I ignore if they come from GLib).

However, with this small program I get a lot of ["possibly lost" leaks](http://pastebin.com/7JAzAxzP). I have also tried other prefixes, such as `G_DEBUG=resident-modules` (suggested [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind)) and `G_SLICE=debug-blocks` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program)), but the "possibly lost" leaks remain. I also tried several of the [GNOME suppressions](https://github.com/dtrebbien/GNOME.supp), namely the GDK one, but to no avail.

My question is: is my only alternative to create a suppression file for this case or is something wrong with the code?

The program was compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -g -pedantic `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gdk-pixbuf-2.0` pixbuf.c -o pixbuf `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 gdk-pixbuf-2.0`
```

I'm using GDK-Pixbuf 2.30.7 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the "possibly lost" blocks I see are from when types are registered with GObject.  These are really still reachable, it's just that valgrind doesn't understand how to reach them (admittedly it is a bit weird, I don't blame valgrind for being confused), so it reports them as "possibly lost" instead of "still reachable".

There is nothing wrong with your code, and there isn't really a leak in glib.  You should use a suppression file.

Comment: More information on suppression files: https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind

Answer (score 0):

If gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file() fails for some reason (for example, the file does not exist), "buf" will be assigned to NULL and the error will be returned via "err".
Then g_assert_no_error(err) will terminate the program, but it will not free the memory to which "err" points. You'd be better off if you manage the error yourself and free "err" with g_free_error(err).
After the call to "gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file" remove the rest of the code replacing it by the following and see what you get as a result from Valgrind:

```
if (!buf) {
    g_printerr("%s\n", err->message);
    g_free_error(err);
}
else {
    g_object_unref(buf);
}
```

By the way, I'm not very familiar with Valgrind, I'm just pointing out the possible memory leak. Although at that point your program would have terminated and the kernel might be smart enough to reclaim the memory block it allocated to the program.

Comment: I believe you're missing the point. This is simply a code example, it's not production code. And of course the error is not occurring (when it occurs, g_assert_no_error() prints an error message). Thus the memory should be freed, which Valgrind reports otherwise.