# C memory allocation issue

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have an algorithm in c in which memory is allocated using malloc many times.  I wanted to write a function that would free that memory when the program is all finished but I am unsure how to structure it.  Would it just be multiple calls to `free()`?  I am rather new to C and memory allocation so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Program:

```
typedef struct State State;
typedef struct Suffix Suffix;

struct State {  /* prefix + suffix list */
    char*   pref[NPREF];    /* prefix words */
    Suffix* suf;            /* list of suffixes */
    State*  next;           /* next in hash table */
};

struct Suffix { /* list of suffixes */
    char *  word;           /* suffix */
    Suffix* next;           /* next in list of suffixes */
};
```

Comment: I would recommend including only the relevant snippets of code

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear memory"? Replace with zeroes? For what reason?

Answer (score 2):

Every call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`, using the value of the pointer that was returned by `malloc`.

You'll need to store the values returned by `malloc` in your program using some sort of container, such as an array, a linked list, and call `free` on those values before returning from `main`.

Write a function along the lines of:

```
void freeMemory()
{
   int i = 0;
   State* sp = NULL;
   State* tmp = NULL;

   for ( i = 0; i < NHASH; ++i )
   {
      sp = statetab[i];
      while ( sp != NULL )
      {
         tmp = sp->next;
         free(sp);
         sp = tmp;
      }
   }
}
```

and call it from `main` before the `return` statement.

Comment: "Every call to malloc _must_ have a corresponding free". I would say that every `malloc` _should_ have a corresponding `free`. Libraries such as GTK [don't always bother with `free`ing memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program)

Comment: @John, you'll need to traverse the list and call `free` on each pointer.