# Valgrind and gtk linking

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, valgrind

I have came around something strange with valgrind lately. If I write for instance a simple `test.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  printf("hello\n");
}
```

and compile it with this command: `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) -g3 -O0` and then check for memory leaks with: `valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out` I get something like:

```
==7588== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7588== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7588== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7588== Command: ./a.out
==7588== 
hello
==7588== 
==7588== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7588==     in use at exit: 51,837 bytes in 245 blocks
==7588==   total heap usage: 1,551 allocs, 1,306 frees, 394,322,404 bytes allocated
==7588== 
==7588== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 89 of 244
==7588==    at 0x4C2A987: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7588==    by 0x6DE35B1: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B70294: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B73F92: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B5464B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B4E67D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x400F279: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588==    by 0x400F38A: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588==    by 0x4000DB9: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588== 
==7588== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 90 of 244
==7588==    at 0x4C28C10: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7588==    by 0x4C2AADE: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7588==    by 0x6DE361D: g_realloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B70148: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B73F92: g_type_register_fundamental (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B5464B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x6B4E67D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==7588==    by 0x400F279: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588==    by 0x400F38A: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588==    by 0x4000DB9: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so)
==7588== 
                               .
                               .
                               .
==7588== 
==7588== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7588==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7588==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7588==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
==7588==    still reachable: 50,485 bytes in 227 blocks
==7588==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==7588==                         newarray           : 1,536 bytes in 16 blocks
==7588==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7588== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7588== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==7588== 
==7588== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7588== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Whereas if I compile it normally, with: `gcc -g3 -O0 test.c` and then check for memory leaks with: `valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`, I obviously don't get any memory leaks:

```
==7734== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7734== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7734== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7734== Command: ./a.out
==7734== 
hello
==7734== 
==7734== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7734==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7734==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==7734== 
==7734== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7734== 
==7734== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7734== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So my question is: why does linking gtk generate so many memory leaks ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much, but even with `valgrind ./a --suppression=/path/to/gtk3.supp`, with `gtk3.supp` generated from [https://github.com/dtrebbien/GNOME.supp](https://github.com/dtrebbien/GNOME.supp) I still get the memory leaks, even though I must admit it answers partly my question. So if I understand well, there's not much I can do about it ?