# Use gtk status icon without memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to use a [gtk status icon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html), but I do not know how to do that without causing memory leak.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *window;
GtkStatusIcon *tray_icon;

static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
   window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
   gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
   gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
   gtk_widget_show_all (window);

   return; // <-- When this is commented out, valgrind finds memory leak.
   tray_icon = gtk_status_icon_new();
   gtk_status_icon_set_visible(tray_icon, TRUE);
   gtk_status_icon_set_tooltip_text(tray_icon, "abc");
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   GtkApplication *app;
   int status;

   app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
   g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
   status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
   g_object_unref (app);

   // Here I am trying to clean it up somehow.
   gtk_status_icon_set_visible(tray_icon, FALSE);
   g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(tray_icon));

   return status;
}
```

When status icon is not used (see return statement with comment in the code), valgrind does not find any definitely or indirectly lost blocks. With status icon valgrind reports this:

> definitely lost: 2,608 bytes in 7 blocks
>
> indirectly lost: 13,745 bytes in 554 blocks

How should I correct the code to display status icon without causing memory leak?

Comment: For what its worth, status icons are officially deprecated as of 3.14.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Yes, they are. But I would like to use them anyway, because notifications do not suit my needs.

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate that there is a memory leak, only that valgrind complains of one. GTK and other complex libraries use allocation patterns that are misreported as leaks by tools like valgrind. A simple way to test whether you're dealing with a real memory leak or not is to wrap the suspect code (and its cleanup) in an infinite loop and observe the process using `top` or equivalent. If its memory grows without bounds, then you have a leak on hand.

Comment: This deprecated code does abandon memory, about 8kb and about 0.1kb every time the tray icon is "destroyed" by g_object_unref and recreated, but it doesn't matter because an application should not be destroying and recreating tray icons, just setting them to visible or invisible, and once created a tray icon is considered "lost memory" or memory that will be allocated for the rest of the process, it's part of the design pattern to not be able to destroy the status icon and it's memory to be abandoned until deallocated at exit.

Comment: @Motomotes Whoa, thank you for your clarification of seven years old problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purposes the answer to this question was that there is no way to make valgrind report no losses on my leak free program. There are various suppression files available, including [one referenced by the people at GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind). There are a significant number of bugs posted against GTK+ relating to this concern, and at least a few [stack overflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program). I found that none of the suppression files I tried worked for me, and generating my own was a waste of time.

Comment: After more than a year I accept this as a solution. Now I understand why everybody is complaining about GTK. I think your answer describes situation well.