# Valgrind OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, valgrind

Here is my test program:

```
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::VideoCapture videoCapture(argv[1]);
    cv::Mat frame;
    videoCapture.read(frame);
    return 0;
}
```

I run this program like this:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./GyroRecord ./walks6/w63/39840012.avi > valgrind_output 2>&1
```

So that the entire output is saved in the `valgrind_output` file.

The contents of `valgrind_output` can be checked [here](http://txt.do/d1otn).

But, if the link dies in the future, this is the summary:

```
==9677== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9677==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9677==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9677==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
==9677==    still reachable: 166,408 bytes in 1,296 blocks
==9677==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==9677==                         newarray           : 1,536 bytes in 16 blocks
==9677==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9677== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==9677== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==9677== 
==9677== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9677== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I would like to reduce "possibly lost" bytes to 0. Is that possible? Or will I always have some "possibly lost" bytes when using OpenCV?

Comment: Looking at the doc, the destructors should free the memory and there is not much you can do for a leaking library I think. As valgrind offers you can add `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` and compile with `-g` to try to see where the leaks occur.

Comment: Your log is full of still-reachable items (mainly from `g_type_register_fundamental()`).  If you suppress those, you might see the wood amongst the trees.

Comment: Its seems its a Glib error similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program?rq=1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OpenCV` comes with *suppression* files (with the extension `.supp`) for `valgrind` that can be used to hide messages about resources allocated (often early in he program's execution) that will be kept allocated until the program dies and the OS has to clean up the mess.

The suppression files are placed in `/usr/share/OpenCV` (on my system):

Example:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --suppressions=/usr/share/OpenCV/valgrind.supp --suppressions=/usr/share/OpenCV/valgrind_3rdparty.supp ./GyroRecord ./walks6/w63/39840012.avi
```

Using these helped me a lot when running `valgrind` on an `OpenCV` project.

Comment: The argument is  `--suppressions` not `--suppression`. For reference, see [Section 2.5](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html). Additionally, it is also possible to find suppressions files at [opencv/platforms/scripts/](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/platforms/scripts).

Comment: @AlexBailo Oh, thanks, I updated it. I don't have a system to test this on myself anymore. Does `valgrind` still take the suppressions arguments _after_ the program one wants to execute? I remember that confused me back when I used `valgrind`.

Comment: This one works for me ```valgrind --leak-check=yes --suppressions=/usr/share/OpenCV/valgrind.supp --suppressions=/usr/share/OpenCV/valgrind_3rdparty.supp ./GyroRecord ./walks6/w63/39840012.avi ```

Comment: @AlexBailo That's good news. I updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks again!