# Valgrind reports a memory leak but does not show call stack

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

We use `valgrind` to test memory leak.
The valgrind reports a memory leak but is not able to show call stack (shown below)

```
==330720== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3,627 of 3,683
==330720==    at 0x297D90C8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==330720==    by 0x4AD9433B: ???
==330720==
```

despite we have ensured the build type is debug, and added `-g` and `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` flags, and followed the instructions from [valgrind FAQ document](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports) (e.g., add `--caller-num` arg to valgrind), the problem still remains.

then we tried to use `vgdb` to debug the program, we set serval breakpoints (shown below).

```cpp
int main() {
    { 
        /* breakpoint #1 : before Load Model */
        ....
        ....

        /* breakpoint #2 : before Load Images using OpenCV */
        ...
        ...

        /* breakpoint #3 : before do inference */
        ...
        ...

        /* breakpoint #4 : before release resources */
        ...
        ...
    }
    /* breakpoint #5 : after all the resources released, 
                       ensured by the nested scope above */
    return 0;
}
```

The valgrind reports no memory leaks at all these breakpoints.

But in final report (i.e., after main() exited, which GDB cannot track), valgrind reports the `72,704 bytes` of definite memory leaks.

How can I get the call stack of the reported memory leak, or how can I location the where the memory leaks?

---

EDIT: I think this may not caused by globally allocated objects? I tested this simple  code.

```cpp
class Test{
public:
    Test() { int* p = new int[10]; }
};
Test instance;
int main() {  }
```

the valgrind does show the call stack outside the `main()`

```
==23741== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==23741==    at 0x4C3289F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23741==    by 0x1086FB: Test::Test() (in /home/***/testmem)
==23741==    by 0x1086CD: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (in /home/***/testmem)
==23741==    by 0x1086E3: _GLOBAL__sub_I_instance (in /home/***/testmem)
==23741==    by 0x10875C: __libc_csu_init (in /home/***/testmem)
==23741==    by 0x51E8C17: (below main) (libc-start.c:266)
```

---

EDIT: the libraries linked with

They are mainly Cuda and OpenCV libraries

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff94a5c000)
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 => /home/×××/debug/samples/humanuid/../../OpenCV/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 (0x0000ffff6b9a2000)
    libopencv_core.so.4.1 => /home/×××/debug/samples/humanuid/../../OpenCV/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1 (0x0000ffff6b6eb000)
    libnvinfer.so.8 => /home/×××/debug/samples/humanuid/../../lib_static/tensorrt/lib/libnvinfer.so.8 (0x0000ffff4ef13000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff4eec7000)
    libcudart.so.11.0 => /usr/local/cuda-11.4/targets/aarch64-linux/include/../lib/libcudart.so.11.0 (0x0000ffff4ee12000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff4ec2d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff4eb83000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff4eb5f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff4e9ec000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff94a2c000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffff4e9d8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000ffff4e9c0000)
    libnvdla_compiler.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvdla_compiler.so (0x0000ffff4e3fc000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x0000ffff4e3d8000)
    libnvmedia.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvmedia.so (0x0000ffff4e370000)
    libnvmedia_tensor.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvmedia_tensor.so (0x0000ffff4e34f000)
    libnvmedia_dla.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvmedia_dla.so (0x0000ffff4e336000)
    libnvos.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvos.so (0x0000ffff4e316000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x0000ffff4e18b000)
    libnvvideo.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvvideo.so (0x0000ffff4e0b4000)
    libnvsocsys.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvsocsys.so (0x0000ffff4e0a0000)
    libnvrm_mem.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_mem.so (0x0000ffff4e089000)
    libnvrm_host1x.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_host1x.so (0x0000ffff4e069000)
    libnvrm_surface.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_surface.so (0x0000ffff4e02b000)
    libnvtvmr.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvtvmr.so (0x0000ffff4df35000)
    libnvrm_chip.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_chip.so (0x0000ffff4df21000)
    libnvrm_sync.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_sync.so (0x0000ffff4df0b000)
    libnvdc.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvdc.so (0x0000ffff4deec000)
    libnvparser.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvparser.so (0x0000ffff4dea3000)
    libnvdla_runtime.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvdla_runtime.so (0x0000ffff4de1c000)
    libnvrm_stream.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_stream.so (0x0000ffff4de02000)
    libnvsciipc.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvsciipc.so (0x0000ffff4dde0000)
    libnvimp.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvimp.so (0x0000ffff4ddcb000)
```

---

EDIT: I have added a breakpoint at address `0x4AD9433B`, the GDB shows

```
(gdb) break *0x4AD9433B
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4ad9433b
(gdb) c
Continuing.
warning: Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libnvrtc.so"
[Inferior 1 (Remote target) exited normally]
```

so I can confirm that this address is inside the `libnvrtc.so`, maybe caused by CUDA library?

---

### FINAL EDIT AND SOLUTIONS TO MY PROBLEM:

**After I post ["
Valgrind reports memory leakage on libnvrtc.so "](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/valgrind-reports-memory-leakage-on-libnvrtc-so/221887/3) on nvidia forum, with the help of nvidia stuffs, I know that, it's definite that the problem is caused by standard C++ library, an emergency pool, will release at program exit by the system, which works well while the library is static-linked (also reported as still reachable by valgrind), but if dlopen then dlclose it,  the unreleased emergency pool will no longer accessible via any pointers (just like a dangling pointer). Due to this reason, the valgrind reported the emergency pool as definite loss.**

**The solution is quiet simple, just static-link the library that contains an emergency memory pool (in my case, libnvrtc.so), the problem sloves. Since the emergency pool becomes always reachable,  no definite loss any more!**

Comment: Is the program compiled with debug information?

Comment: It is possible that there are global objects that allocate memory that are created  before main is entered & destroyed after main exits.

Comment: @Havenard yes, and can hit breakpoints and print call stack using GDB normally.

Comment: What libraries have you linked with? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AviBerger I have tested memory leaks on global allocated object, the valgrind can print the call stack normally. see updates of my question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo   we linked with CUDA and OpenCV libraries. Because it's a huge project with many dependencies including many-dependencies static-linked, it's hard to make a minimal example.

Comment: Does this [Valgrind OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61785698/7582247) answer help? TL;DR; OpenCV leaks on purpose. You need to use suppression files to hide those leaks when using valgrind

Comment: If the same leak happens deterministically for each run from the same address 0x4AD9433B, you might start your program under valgrind+vgdb, set a breakpoint at this address and then investigate what valgrind and/or gdb stacktrace logic gives.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added these 2 suppersions but the memory leak remains, maybe not caused by OpenCV?

Comment: @Acane I would search for `valgrind` and all the libraries you use. It's not uncommon that they need suppression files. CUDA has a chapter on running valgrind too (although I didn't find anything about suppression files).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks.  I have mentioned that the same leak is deterministically from 0x4AD9433B just as @phd says. The leaks is from `libnvrtc.so` from CUDA library.

Comment: @Acane: as the leak happens deterministically under valgrind+gdb, what is the output of the GDB backtrace command when the breakpoint is hit ? And what is then the output of the valgrind gdb monitor command  "monitor v.info scheduler" ?  Note also  "monitor v.info unwind  0x4AD9433B (somewhat before and/or after) might explain why the unwind fails.

Comment: @Acane: also, seeing the message 'unloaded shared library", you might try with the valgrind option --keep-debuginfo=yes (so as to keep the debug info for unloaded shared libs). That might help to produce complete stack traces.

Comment: @phd despite I added --keep-debuginfo=yes, the libnvrtc.so is still unloaded, cannot cannot hit the breakpoint at 0x4AD9433B

Comment: @phd  after add keep-debuginfo, valgrind prints the library name (`libnvrtc.so`) after `???`, but valgrind does not print deeper call stack

Comment: @Acane if your application does a lot of load/unload, you have to be sure you put the breakpoint at the moment the library is loaded and before the breakpoint code is executed.  Note that keep-debuginfo does only tell valgrind to keep the debug info. It still  unloads the library when required by the application.   Possibly/likely, the code in libnvrtc.so is very special and the valgrind unwind logic cannot do a backtrace. This is why it would be interesting to compare with a GDB backtrace.