# Valgrind possibly lost in _dl_init libgobject libglib

Tags: c, gcc, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am trying to debug memory problems with my program, however the error messages that are coming out of valgrind are unhelpful. Here is an example.

```
==3944334== 184 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 224 of 239
==3944334==    at 0x483BD7B: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:836)
==3944334==    by 0x5675928: g_realloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x55CD2E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x55C8D4C: g_type_register_static (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x55E0EF2: g_param_type_register_static (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x55C1977: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x55BFB4C: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.6400.2)
==3944334==    by 0x4011099: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib/ld-2.31.so)
==3944334==    by 0x40111A0: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.31.so)
==3944334==    by 0x4002139: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.31.so)
==3944334==    by 0x2: ???
==3944334==    by 0x1FFF0002DA: ???
```

I want to know if these errors are a problem. If they are I want to know how to solve them, if they aren't I want to know how to suppress them.

Usually if I encounter an error in valgrind I can find a function name I recognize and a line number and solve the error from there. However in this case there is not a single function name I recognize as mine across all the errors. Here is how I'm running valgrind.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes -s ./logdraw -f log.txt
```

And here is the valgrind summary.

```
==3944839== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3944839==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3944839==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3944839==      possibly lost: 1,352 bytes in 18 blocks
==3944839==    still reachable: 47,893 bytes in 221 blocks
==3944839==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==3944839==                         newarray           : 1,536 bytes in 16 blocks
==3944839==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3944839== 
==3944839== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

To complicate matters further I can put "return 0;" as the first line in my main function and still get back all of these errors when running valgrind. I thought I could triangulate the problem using that but apparently I cannot.

Here is my makefile, if it matters.

```
logdraw: log.o gtkUI.o
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -g -Wall -o logdraw logdraw.o gtkUI.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

log.o: logdraw.c gtkUI.h
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -g -Wall -c logdraw.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -O0 -I.

gtkUI.o: gtkUI.c gtkUI.h
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -g -Wall -c gtkUI.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I know there is some [memory weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659781/memory-leaks-in-gtk-hello-world-program) in gtk3 so I have commented out the call I made to the functions in my gtkUI.c file as well as the `#include` for that file. I don't know if it could still be affecting me.

Comment: On the face of it, you are compiling and linking with `-g`, and yet the output from `valgrind` suggests you are not using `-g`.  Have you rebuilt from scratch?  Have you looked at the file types of the `.o` files — and the executable?

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, I wonder if the leak you're puzzled about is from startup code, that should be suppressed because there's nothing you can do about that.  The `dl_init` function is in `/usr/lib/ld-2.31.so`, which is the dynamic loader, so it could be that this leak should be suppressed.

Comment: You might take a look at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345307 You might need a recent enough valgrind and/or a recent enough library. In any case, this stack trace is clearly related to shared library initialization, not related to your code. So, either with newer versions, it disappeared, otherwise you can safely suppress it.

Comment: I looked at the file classification in ranger. logdraw.o and gtkUI.o both say they have debug_info.
I updated everything with -Syu to get the most recent valgrind and libraries, but I'm still getting the errors.
I compiled in a way that completely avoided GTK, and the errors went away, so the problem is likely there. Once I've figured out how to suppress the errors that come out of GTK I'll make a post saying if that did or did no solve my problem, and how it can be replicated if it did.

Comment: You can get Valgrind to generate the suppressions for you.  You save them in a file, and then specify the suppressions file on the command line to use them.

Comment: I found out about that here, https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto , and I'm working out how to make it apply to my situation.